# Poetry + Tox + Pytest seems to ALWAYS run every test

Tags: python, python-poetry, tox

I have an issue with [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) + [tox](https://tox.wiki/en/stable/) + [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x) where if I run `poetry run tox tests` or `poetry run tox py39-test` every test env runs. Additionally, if I use `py39-test`, then it seems to skip the pytest commands all together. Using `tox <command>` from a `poetry shell` doesn't change how it outputs.

> I am going to try and post specific code on my issue. However, code snippets and project can be found at https://github.com/flamusdiu/xleapp.

First, [log output from `tox tests` (gist)](https://gist.github.com/flamusdiu/780c8311ff65edc49a60fdfe05c6ccc6) shows that I ran the tool but both the tests and the lint env ran.

```
[tox]
isolated_build = true
envlist = tests, lint 

[testenv:tests]
commands =
  pytest -vv --cov={envsitepackagesdir}/xleapp --cov-report xml --cov-report html --ignore=data
deps =
  requests
  tqdm
extras =
  tests

[testenv:lint]
commands =
   black -S src/
   flakeheaven lint src/
extras = 
   lint
```

If you change the `envlist` to `{py39, py310}-{tests, lint}`, then you get this [tox error from `tox py39-tests` (gist)](https://gist.github.com/flamusdiu/d7c69db385977fcfad44e7b9df4cbb3f) which shows each of the tests runs but `run-test` never runs. It seems to skip any commands.This **should** run the commands for each tests.

Also, when running a specific python version (`py39`-) should run only that test env.

I have looked everywhere trying to figure out what is going on. Maybe its a bug? Maybe it's something else?

References:

- https://levelup.gitconnected.com/python-a-toxic-work-environment-tox-poetry-b8200563c474
- https://tox.wiki/en/stable/example/package.html#poetry
- https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/explanation/goodpractices.html

The references are just some of the background on what I have setup. I am using the `pyproject.toml` file and copying to the `tox.ini` file has the same problem.

---

**Update 1**

Changed the tox configuration to:

```
[tox]
isolated_build = true

[testenv]
whitelist_externals = poetry
commands =
  poetry install -v
  poetry run pytest tests/
extras=
   tests

[testenv:lint]
commands =
   black -S src/
   flakeheaven lint src/
extras = 
   lint
```

This works. @jürgen-gmach pointed out the slight issue with my current build which was driving me bonkers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of issues...

a) remove this from your `pyproject.toml` as you want to create a `tox.ini` anyway - and that is preferable

```
[tool.tox]
legacy_tox_ini = """
[tox]
isolated_build = true
envlist = {py39, py310}-{tests, lint}

[testenv:tests]
commands =
  pytest -vv --cov={envsitepackagesdir}/xleapp --cov-report xml --cov-report html --ignore=data
deps =
  requests
  tqdm
extras =
  tests

[testenv:lint]
commands =
   black -S src/
   flakeheaven lint src/
extras = 
   lint
  """
```

b) your `tox.ini` is almost ok

Usually, you have one base `testenv` for all tests, and without a dedicated name. Then you can run tests for e.g. Python 3.9 with `tox -e py39`. And your linter with `tox -e lint`, or all with `tox`.

```
[tox]
isolated_build = true
envlist = py39, lint 

[testenv]
commands =
  pytest -vv --cov={envsitepackagesdir}/xleapp --cov-report xml --cov-report html --ignore=data
deps =
  requests
  tqdm
extras =
  tests

[testenv:lint]
commands =
   black -S src/
   flakeheaven lint src/
extras = 
   lint
```

c) The deps `requests` and `tqdm` is a code smell - these are test dependencies, so they should be installed via the `extras = tests` not separately.

d) you should follow the [official documentation](https://python-poetry.org/docs/faq/#is-tox-supported) for poetry about tox and use a testenv like this

```
[testenv]
whitelist_externals = poetry
commands =
    poetry install -v
    poetry run pytest tests/
deps = poetry
```

I added `deps = poetry` as I do not have poetry globally installed, as I do not use it (except when trying to help users using tox :-) ).

e) You will not use poetry to run tox to run pytest, but you will run tox to run poetry to run pytest.

So with the above testenv, you could run the Python 3.9 tests with:

```
tox -e py39
```

Python 3.10

```
tox -e py310
```

linters

```
tox -e lint
```

P.S.: as a bonus, you could consider to use pre-commit to run all your linters: https://pre-commit.ci/

P.P.S.: I am one of the tox maintainer, I never used poetry before, but I hope this helps to get you going.

Comment: I need to setup pre-commit but I'm just moonlighting as a dev. I only just recently started doing testing for this major project.

As for requests and tqdm, that's true. I moved everything around and just never moved them to it.

As for the `tox.ini` vs `pyproject.toml`, I've done both seems to work **nearly** the same.